# How to run HBase shell against a remote cluster

Tags: configuration, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

I'm running HBase in pseudo-distributed mode on my workstation.  We also have HBase running on  a cluster.  Using the HBase shell, I'd like to access the HBase instance that's running on the cluster from my workstation.  I would like to do this without logging into one of the cluster machines.

With Hadoop, you can run jobs on a remote cluster by specifying the -conf parameter and supplying an alternate version of hadoop-site.xml.  Is there an equivalent for the HBase shell?

I'm running cloudera cdh3u3 on my workstation and on the cluster machines.

Comment: Not sure, but I think making changes to the following conf files might do the job. For hadoop: core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml. For hbase: hbase-site.xml. You could create multiple versions of these files and switch between them as needed.

Comment: @mohit6up you should make that an answer (particularly since it is the correct one)

Comment: Good idea!  Although I'd prefer something like the -conf param, I can just pop in and change the actual config files.  Would I need to re-start the services after updating the configs?

Comment: No, no re-starts should be needed.

Comment: @sangfroid no- you need to change them on the client machine only (where you run hbase shell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make changes to the following conf files.

- For hadoop: core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml.
- For hbase: hbase-site.xml.

You could create multiple versions of these files and switch between them as needed.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using following command:

```
hbase --config "path to folder with config files" shell
```

Folder with configuration should contain at least hbase-site.xml with content:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
 </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
 <value>zk1,zk2,zk3</value>
  </property>
   <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
<!--or /hbase-->
        <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

change hbase-site.xml add zookeeper host port with hbase server.

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>zk.hostname</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```